# Receiving an intent in Cordova PhoneGap app

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova

I have registered my cordova app for an intent that is fired when a NFC tag is read. The app starts as expected. But I´m not able to get the information of the intent. I tried the 'webintent' plugin, but it always return null.

So how can I get the information of the intent my app was invoked by?

EDIT:

In the 'onDeviceReady' function I call

```
    window.plugins.webintent.getExtra("android.nfc.extra.TAG",
        function(url) {
            alert(url);
        }, function() {
            alert("no extras 'TAG'");
            // There was no extra supplied.
        }
    );
```

I also tried the extra 'android.nfc.extra.NDEF_MESSAGES' but still get 'null'.

Comment: The webintent plugin is, afaik, working. Can you share how you tried to use it?